# how do i stop continuous POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

2 questions: **First**: I have two methods that gets data from the database and place it into each dropdown menu. when i click on second menu it makes continuous post, so there are so many network package that are been sent for the data request and my developer tool gets flooded with posts?

**Second** question is that when i get data from the database how do i perform an action. I am using bootstrap dropdown menu. what i want is when i click on something it should remove the default message and populate the selected text. I have did this but its not selecting data which i am getting from the database. If i manually input data via li then dropdown text changes?

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
            Method();
            Method2();

    $('.menu1').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
   });


    function Method() {
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetService",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (x) {
                var opts = '';
                $.each(x.d, function (i) {
                    opts += '<li>' + this.Name + '</li>';
                });
                $('.menu1').html(opts);
            }
        });
    }

    function Method2() {
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetService2",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (x) {
                var opts = '';
                $.each(x.d, function (i) {
                    opts += '<li>' + this.Name + '</li>';
                });
                $('.menu2').html(opts);
            }
        });
    }



    <div class="drop1" style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" id="Button1" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="dropdown_title">Name:</span><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu1">
       <li><a class=""></a></li>   //this is where 'a' is which will get populated by data from database
    </ul>
</div>
</div>


<div class="drop2" style="display: inline-block;">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="Button2" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="dropdown_title2">Name2:</span><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu2">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Question:
You can OFF the event in the POST process and ON the event AGAIN after SUCCESS ,like below do form submit code

```
var doPost = function() {
    $(this).off('submit', doPost);
    var url = '...',
        data = {...},
        afterPost = function() {
            $('#post-form').on('submit', doPost)
        };
    $.post(url, data, afterPost);
}
$('#post-form').on('submit', doPost);
```

Second Question:
If you want to bind event with the dynamic data, you can do this way:

```
$('.menu1').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

This way can bind event to the DOM created after you bind the event

---

Answer update:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Method(); 
    Method2(); 

    $('.menu1').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $('#dropdown_title').html($(this).find('a').html());
    });
     $('.menu2').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $('#dropdown_title2').html($(this).find('a').html());
    });
});

function Method() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetService",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (x) {
            var opts = '';
            $.each(x.d, function (i) {
                opts += '<li>' + this.Name + '</li>';
            });
            $('.menu1').html(opts);
        }
    });
}

function Method2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetService2",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (x) {
            var opts = '';
            $.each(x.d, function (i) {
                opts += '<li>' + this.Name + '</li>';
            });
            $('.menu2').html(opts);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have place question 2 code in document ready but nothing is happening. If i place a break point and select something from the database i get a message saying Child could not be evolved. What does that means?

Comment: $('.menu1').on('click', 'li',function () {});
ALSO need to include in the document ready function scope

Comment: I have confused about where is your 'a' tag?
I cant find it in your code, but you do $(this).find('a') in your jQuery code

Comment: I maid a mistake i was calling my Method(); and Method2(); through onclick i have updated my question. 'a' will get added in between<ul></ul>. its going to be like this: <li><a class=""></a></li>. I am getting same error:  Child could not be evaluated

Comment: 'Child could not be evaluated' is JavaScript Error?
Which line it's happened?
If it's a error in JavaScript, you can see the error line number in console.

Comment: your success function also need 'a', too.
$.each(x.d, function (i) {
                opts += '<li><a class="">' + this.Name + '</a></li>';
            });
Or, You can't bind $(this).find('a')
$(this) is point to the 'li' element you clicked.

Comment: Thank you it works:) i had to define 'a' in my success handler. Going back to question-1 so many Posts are happening in my Method2 only. Where would i place your given code. will that go in success handler? and i am not submitting anything so do i need onsubmit. i am just selecting two names and searching something on click of a search button?

Comment: the code in your answer is the newest version?
where is your 'button2'?
And I can't understand why your put your ready method in your $.ajax.
your can find detail usage in jquery api document
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: button2 for some reason did not show but its included now in my question. I have not placed my ready method in $.ajax??

Comment: Is any reason for you to do the below code?
var ajReq = $.ajax({ $(document).ready(function () {});
I have never seen this strange usage: put your $(document).ready() in $.ajax.~~
the arguments of $.ajax is like this $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})

Comment: My bad that was my mistake. I have updated my code that shows i am calling my Method and Method2 in document ready function which is more efficient method. But am still getting continues post back? on Method2 only? i still cannot figure that out?